# How to assign literals inside static method in c#?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to assign a text value to a literal inside a catch block I tried this code but in exception its passing null value to **Literal1.Text**

```
         public partial class leadsmg : System.Web.UI.Page
{...
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod]
    public static void Savecmp(Cmpdet user)
    {
        leadsmg ld = new leadsmg();
        string user_Id = HttpContext.Current.Session["id"].ToString();
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(HttpContext.Current.Session["ConnectionString"].ToString());

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into companydet (cname,caddr,cweb,cpno,ccd,uid,cad)values(@Cname,@Caddr,@Cweb,@Cpnno,@Cdate,@Uid,getdate())");

        try
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cname", user.Cname);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Caddr", user.Caddr);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cweb", user.Cweb);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cpnno", user.Cpno);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cdate", user.Cdateadd);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Uid", user_Id);
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            conn.Close();
            ld.Literal1.Text = "Company already exits";//here its passing null value to Literal1.Text
        }
    }.....}
```

**leadsmg** is the main method where **Savecmp** exists.

how to resolve this problem?

Comment: so is it `Literal1` or `literal1`? C# is case-sensitive and you are using 2 different casings (and since you didn't show the definition of `leadsmg` we don't know whether you have two members with those names or not)

Comment: Show the class of leadsmg

Comment: Is `leadsmg` an instance of the `Page`-class? Then you can't instantiate it witht hed efault constructor because all controls will be null. You need to use the correct instance.

Comment: The accepted answer in the duplicate question will not work for this question(it also didn't work for that question). You can't access a page instance from a webmethod.

Comment: @TimSchmelter how can i access page instance from webmethod

Comment: @Suhas: you can't. Don't use a webmethod if you need to access page-controls

Comment: @TimSchmelter then what is the alternative way to handle my exception

Comment: Do a postback as suggested in my answer in the duplicate @Suhas

Comment: @PatrickHofman yeah its working fine its coming out of exception but im not able to print that in **Literal1**

Comment: So it is not working fine. You can return the result of the web method and catch that in your AJAX call client side.

Comment: @PatrickHofman i handled that exception using AJAX call client side now its working fine.